# can't zip folder under linux mint on external ext4 hdd -no permission

Tags: linux, linux-mint, zip

I can't zip a external hdd even if i set the permission to my username.

I tried sudo chown -R user:user /folder/in/media, but i still have no permission to zip via the gui of the system.

i even have no right to zip if i open the folder as root.

i can delete or read everything but not zip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the owner:group may not be enough. Check the permissions of the folder, you are trying to extract to. If the `-x` for `execute` is not set for the user on the folder (as it tends to be with mount points).

Add the `x` flag via command line or gui (as root!) and it schoud work. I do not recommend using the gui via root, but it is possible.

The situation looks like the device is not mounted with your user rights and optimal permission, as it schould, if you plugin a usb-disk. Did you mess with `udev` or so?

Comment: thank you i could finally achieve it by using tar.gz as format and adding * .* for hidden files